# How to display hashmap in Haskell

Tags: haskell

my task is to create menu with four choices:
-add new students
-show all students,
-delete students by ID
-close program.
I used Hashmap for this problem, but the problem is that i have no idea how to display a current list of created students.

My code is presented below:

```
{module StudentApp where
import Data.HashMap.Strict
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
data Student = Student {name::String, age::Int, id::String}
  deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

type Students = HashMap String Student

addStudent:: Students -> IO(Students)
addStudent students = do
    putStrLn ("Student Name")
    name<-getLine
    putStrLn("Student Age")
    age<-readLn :: IO Int
    putStrLn("Student ID")
    id<-getLine
    let s = Student name age id
    let updatedStudents = insert id s students
    return updatedStudents

showStudent:: Students -> IO (Students)
showStudent students = do
    print students  
    return students


deleteStudent:: Students -> IO (Students)
deleteStudent students = do
    putStrLn ("Give student ID to remove")
    id<-getLine
    let updatedStudents = delete id students
    return updatedStudents


menu :: Students -> IO ()
menu students = do
    putStrLn ("1. Add new student")
    putStrLn ("2. Show all students")
    putStrLn ("3. Delete Student by ID")
    putStrLn ("4. Exit program")
    choice<-getLine
    updatedStudents <- case choice of
        "1" -> addStudent students
        "2" -> showStudent students
        "3" -> deleteStudent students
        "4" -> exitSuccess --System.Exit.exitSuccess (zwraca typ IO students)    
    menu updatedStudents
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let students = empty :: Students
    menu students
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Given that the keys `k` and the values `v` are instances of `Show`, then a `HashMap` is an instance of `Show` as well. Indeed in the [source code, we see](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.10.0/docs/src/Data.HashMap.Base.html#line-264):

> ```
> instance (Show k, Show v) => Show (HashMap k v) where
>     showsPrec d m = showParen (d > 10) $
>       showString "fromList " . shows (toList m)
> ```

So we can use [**`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) here to print the content of the `HashMap`. Like:

```
Prelude Data.HashMap.Strict> print (fromList [("id001", Student "Foo" 21 "id001"), ("id003", Student "Bar" 19 "id003")])
fromList [("id003",Student {name = "Bar", age = 19, id = "id003"}),("id001",Student {name = "Foo", age = 21, id = "id001"})]
```

So here `print` contains as argument a `HashMap String Student` we constructed, and this will print the content of the dictionary.

You can make use of [**`ToList :: HashMap k v -> [(k, v)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.10.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#v:toList) as well to convert your `HashMap k v` into a list of key-value tuples, and then thus show the values with some extra functions.

For example we can print every value (here `Student`) on a separate line with:

```
mapM_ (print . snd) (toList myhashmap)
```

In your menu you can thus write:

```
menu :: Students -> IO ()
menu students = do
    putStrLn "1. Add new student"
    putStrLn "2. Show all students"
    putStrLn "3. Delete Student by ID"
    putStrLn "4. Exit program"
    choice <- getLine
    updatedStudents <- case choice of
        "1" -> addStudent students
        --"2" -> showstudent
        "3" -> deleteStudent students
        "4" -> exitSuccess --System.Exit.exitSuccess (zwraca typ IO students)
    print updatedStudents
    menu updatedStudents
```

> **Advise**: In your current program, you constantly use `do` blocks. Typically in a Haskell program, you write the logic that does not require `IO`, a `State`, etc. separately in functions that do a small number of things.

Comment: Thanks for your's response. I understand everything but i still have got problem with priting function in my menu;/  When I add "print updatedStudents program stops.." Can you write whole statement?

Comment: @AdrianKozień: did you by any chance removed the `menu updatedStudents`?

Comment: I edited my post, now there is my last version, but still doesn't work properly

Comment: @AdrianKozień: shouldn't the `do` block of your `showStudent` be *indented*?

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot about it while i was writing post.

Comment: @AdrianKozień: When I run your program, it works properly, I get responses for `showstudent` like `fromList []`, `fromList [("1234",Student {name = "Adrian", age = 21, id = "1234"})]`, etc.

Comment: http://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/1754075---jtxt.html   here is my program and screenshot with error

Comment: @AdrianKozień: you used a tab for the `return`, but four spaces for the `print students`, hence the compiler got confused.

Comment: Thanks for response, now there is no errors but program doesn't work corretly. The situation is: first of all i start program by writing "main", then i choose option 1 (addstudent) - this is correct and then program is going back to the menu . now i'm trying to choose option 2 (show student) and it stucks

Comment: @AdrianKozień: are you sure it did not print the dictionary and rendered the menu again? It is printed on a single line, just above the menu, and after one student, it looks almost exactly as the `Student {...}` record, except for the `fromList [ ... ]`. Here it simply returns to the menu, and thus one can print again, or add an extra student.

Comment: @AdrianKozień: what if you hit enter after that, looks like a buffering problem in the Windows command line :s.

Comment: no reaction, additionally ctrl+z, ctrl+d, ctrl+c don't work too and the only solution is to close window by 'X' button...

Comment: @AdrianKozień: the trouble is that I can not reproduce your problem. I've used the code file in the zip file (well fixed the spacing issue), and then I manage to run it properly.